# Cleaner way to 'sanitize' JTextField input?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, formatted-input

So I'm writing the TextValueChanged handler for a JTextField that takes a long as it's input. It needs to only allow the user to type in valid values between 0 and Long.MAX. If the user types an invalid character, it should strip it, so that the value in the JTextField is always a valid long.

My current code looks like this, but it seems ugly. With no external libs (including Apache Commons), is there a cleaner/simpler way to do this?

```
public void textValueChanged(TextEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JTextField) {
        String text = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
        try {
            // Try to parse cleanly
            long longNum = Long.parseLong(text);
            // Check for < 1 
            if (longNum < 1) throw new NumberFormatException();
            // If we pass, set the value and return
            setOption("FIELDKEY", longNum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            // We failed, so there's either a non-numeric or it's too large.
            String s = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
            // Strip non-numeric characters
            s = s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
            long longNum = -1;
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                /* Really ugly workaround for the fact that a
                 * TextValueChanged event can capture more than one
                 * keystroke at a time, if it's typed fast enough,
                 * so we might have to strip more than one
                 * character. */
                Exception e3;
                do {
                    e3 = null;
                    try {
                        // Try and parse again
                        longNum = Long.parseLong(s);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
                        // We failed, so it's too large.
                        e3 = e2;
                        // Strip the last character and try again.
                        s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
                    }
                    // Repeat
                } while (e3 != null);
            }
            // We parsed, so add it (or blank it if it's < 1) and return.
            setOption("FIELDKEY", (longNum < 1 ? 0 : longNum));
        }
    }
}
```

The field is constantly repopulated from a getOption(key) call, so to 'store' the value, just pass it to that call.

Comment: What's wrong with using a `JFormattedTextField` instead?

Comment: I could do that, but it's behavior doesn't match what I'd like. If focus is lost, you either lose the changes and revert to the previously saved text (which I don't want), or keep the invalid text (which I also don't want).

To force this behavior I'd just have to override it and write the some code in a different event.

Comment: The problem with `JFormattedTextField` is that you can enter anything you like. Only after you have exited the text field the validation takes place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) is a good solution for your case.

[The Definitive Guide to Java Swing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594479) by John Zukowski has an excellent example on pages 542-546 showing a custom document filter for limiting an integer range.

Providing custom DocumentFilter should easily accommodate the requirement to strip off the unwanted characters upon copy/pase as you have specified in one of the comments.

Comment: I looked briefly though DocumentFilter and thought I saw something that made me think it was a deal-breaker. I'm not super familiar with it, so it's entirely possible I was mistaken. I'll take another look, thanks.

Comment: As Zukowski puts it: While you can certainly create a custom subclass of Document, the more object-oriented approach is to create a filter, as you don't want to change the Document; you just want to limit the input into the model.

Comment: I doubt I'll use this for this instance, but after some research I'll probably go back and create some generic DocumentFilters and toss them in a util package. I think there will be a tad too much overhead to that for me to use them immediately, but they'll make a good long-term solution. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), discussed in [*How to Use the Focus Subsystem: Validating Input*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).

Comment: This has the same problem as the JFormattedTextField, that it only works when gaining/losing focus, and I need this field to have continual validation.

Answer (score 0):

I have this for the float you can use for the long

```
class DoubleTextDocument extends PlainDocument {
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null)
            return;
        String oldString = getText(0, getLength());
        String newString = oldString.substring(0, offs) + str
                + oldString.substring(offs);
        try {
            Float.parseFloat(newString + "0");
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and in your extended `JTextField` you can use

`@Override`

```
protected Document createDefaultModel() {
    return new DoubleTextDocument();
}
```

Comment: The main problem I had with the Document implementation is that it doesn't quite work the way I'd like. If multiple characters are added and only a few are invalid, it will eat all of them and revert to the previous safe value, rather than just clearing the invalid ones. 

That being said, it's the next best alternative I've thought of so far.

I'm hoping someone has something that's essentially a refactored and better thought out version of what I have lying around.

Comment: Ok so you need a scenario where in if a copy paste of alphanumeric text takes place only the numeric parts need to be considered

Comment: Yep. Sorry, I should have specified that that was a constraint in the main post.